# Derivative of a constant matrix to the $t$th power with respect to the exponent $t$.

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a constant matrix. Is there any useful formula for the derivative of $A^t$ with respect to $t$?

I know that for a matrix which can be represented as an exponential $\exp(B)$, we will have $\exp(B)^t = \exp(tB),$ and so $\frac d{dt} \exp(tB) = B\exp(tB)=B^{\frac 12}\exp(tB)B^{\frac12}.$

This suggests to me that for a general matrix $A$ the answer might be $\log(A)A$, where this makes sense. Is this correct?

Comment: The exponential doesn't even make sense in general, eg some matrices don't have square roots.

Comment: Which is why I said "for a matrix which can be represented as an exponential". I changed my wording to be even more clear.

Comment: But then you said "for a general matrix," which implies to me that you were expecting the expression to always make sense.

Comment: Great catch, Qiaochu. I edited the question.

Comment: If $A$ is non-singular, [it has a logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix), so your second paragraph is sufficient. If $A$ is singular, how are you defining $A^t$?